# Android drawing semi circle with canvas

Tags: android

Can anyone help me out on how I going to draw semicircle of the picture below with canvas and also how to detect the collection of the drawing object?

[image: Drawing Object]

I had try to draw it using XML and i dont know how to detect the collision of it.  I just want to detect the collision of the black part but not the whole circle.
Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

I've just done something similar, with a custom View:

```
class SemiCircleView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val paint: Paint = Paint()
    private var rectangle: RectF? = null
    private var margin: Float

    init {
        paint.isAntiAlias = true
        paint.color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAquamarine)
        paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        paint.strokeWidth = 5.dpToPx()
        margin = 3.dpToPx() // margin should be >= strokeWidth / 2 (otherwise the arc is cut)
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        if (rectangle == null) {
            rectangle = RectF(0f + margin, 0f + margin, width.toFloat() - margin, height.toFloat() - margin)
        }
        canvas.drawArc(rectangle!!, 90f, 180f, false, paint)
    }

}
```

Add it you your XML layout like this:

```
<com.example.view.SemiCircleView
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"/>
```

That's the result:

[image: Android semi circle canvas setArc]

---

In my case I want to **programmatically control the % of the circle being drawn**, so I've added a method `setArcProportion` that controls that:

```
class SemiCircleView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val mainPaint: Paint = Paint()
    private val backgroundPaint: Paint = Paint()
    private var rectangle: RectF? = null
    private var margin: Float
    private var arcProportion: Float = 0f

    init {
        mainPaint.isAntiAlias = true
        mainPaint.color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorLutea)
        mainPaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        mainPaint.strokeWidth = 5.dpToPx()
        backgroundPaint.isAntiAlias = true
        backgroundPaint.color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black_08)
        backgroundPaint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        backgroundPaint.strokeWidth = 5.dpToPx()
        margin = 3.dpToPx() // margin should be >= strokeWidth / 2 (otherwise the arc is cut)
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        if (rectangle == null) {
            rectangle = RectF(0f + margin, 0f + margin, width.toFloat() - margin, height.toFloat() - margin)
        }
        canvas.drawArc(rectangle!!, -90f, arcProportion * 360, false, mainPaint)
        // This 2nd arc completes the circle. Remove it if you don't want it
        canvas.drawArc(rectangle!!, -90f + arcProportion * 360, (1 - arcProportion) * 360, false, backgroundPaint)
    }

    /**
     * @param arcProportion The proportion of the semi circle arc, from 0 to 1. Setting 0 makes the arc invisible, and 1
     * makes a whole circle.
     */
    fun setArcProportion(arcProportion: Float) {
        this.arcProportion = arcProportion
        invalidate()
    }

}
```

So if I do `semiCircleView.setArcProportion(0.62f)` I have:

[image: Android semi circle canvas setArc]

**Bonus** - To make the arc grow with an animation modify `setArcProportion` like this:

```
private const val ANIMATION_BASE_DURATION_MS: Long = 500 // milliseconds

fun setArcProportion(arcProportion: Float) {
    ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, arcProportion).apply {
        interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator()
        // The animation duration is longer for a larger arc
        duration = ANIMATION_BASE_DURATION_MS + (arcProportion * ANIMATION_BASE_DURATION_MS).toLong()
        addUpdateListener { animator ->
            this@SemiCircleView.arcProportion = animator.animatedValue as Float
            this@SemiCircleView.invalidate()
        }
        start()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. In your onDraw method draw a circle .

   canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 10, paint);
2. Now draw a rect with your background colour

   ```
   Paint fillBackgroundPaint = new Paint();
   fillBackgroundPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
   fillBackgroundPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
   canvas.drawRect(x,y+10,x+10,y-10);
   ```

This should serve the purpose.