# Android canvas draws curved semicircle

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want to draw smooth semicircle with *drawArc()* method. But what I get is:
[image]

```
        RectF oval = new RectF(x - cornerRadius, y - cornerRadius, x + cornerRadius,y + cornerRadius);
        canvas.drawArc(oval, start, 180, true, cornerPaint);
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you try this answer here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56427817/9715339

Comment: No, but due your comment I have reviewed my code and have found the source of problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem has gone after I have created Paint from zero, not copying it from another Paint. Seems like another paint had parameters that affected line shape.